# Get comments- text or text with images into json with python, Rest api

Tags: python, api, rest, azure-devops

Below is the json which i am trying to iterate to get the text of the comments

```
commondata = {
    "totalCount": 2,
    "count": 2,
    "comments": [
        {
            "mentions": [],
            "workItemId": 7107,
            "id": 9930470,
            "version": 1,
            "text": "<div style=\"box-sizing:border-box;font-family:&quot;Segoe UI&quot;, system-ui, &quot;Apple Color Emoji&quot;, &quot;Segoe UI Emoji&quot;, sans-serif;orphans:2;widows:2;\">So we need to add this directory of sample </div><div style=\"box-sizing:border-box;font-family:&quot;Segoe UI&quot;, system-ui, &quot;Apple Color Emoji&quot;, &quot;Segoe UI Emoji&quot;, sans-serif;orphans:2;widows:2;\"><br></div><div style=\"box-sizing:border-box;font-family:&quot;Segoe UI&quot;, system-ui, &quot;Apple Color Emoji&quot;, &quot;Segoe UI Emoji&quot;, sans-serif;orphans:2;widows:2;\"><img src=\"data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEAYABgAAD/
}
        {
            "mentions": [],
            "workItemId": 7107,
            "id": 9930469,
            "version": 1,
            "text": "<div>It does not make sense to files.</div><div><br></div><div>We first need to have a sample models folder and then browse to it. <a href=\"https://azuredevops.com/8dd91aab-0dce/_workitems/edit/7120\" data-vsp-mention=\"version:9.0\”>#7120</a>&nbsp;<br></div>"
        }
    ]
}
```

with rest api using I am trying to generate JSON. I have two 2 comments one with text + image and the other just text. Below is the code I tried, but the 2nd comment includes the first comment too which is wrong.

```
    def getComments():
       common_data = {
    "totalCount": 2,
    "count": 2,
    "comments": [
        {
            "mentions": [],
            "workItemId": 7107,
            "id": 9930470,
            "version": 1,
            "text": "<div style=\"box-sizing:border-box;font-family:&quot;Segoe UI&quot;, system-ui, &quot;Apple Color Emoji&quot;, &quot;Segoe UI Emoji&quot;, sans-serif;orphans:2;widows:2;\">So we need to add this directory of sample </div><div style=\"box-sizing:border-box;font-family:&quot;Segoe UI&quot;, system-ui, &quot;Apple Color Emoji&quot;, &quot;Segoe UI Emoji&quot;, sans-serif;orphans:2;widows:2;\"><br></div><div style=\"box-sizing:border-box;font-family:&quot;Segoe UI&quot;, system-ui, &quot;Apple Color Emoji&quot;, &quot;Segoe UI Emoji&quot;, sans-serif;orphans:2;widows:2;\"><img src=\"data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEAYABgAAD/
}
        {
            "mentions": [],
            "workItemId": 7107,
            "id": 9930469,
            "version": 1,
            "text": "<div>It does not make sense to files.</div><div><br></div><div>We first need to have a sample models folder and then browse to it. <a href=\"https://azuredevops.com/8dd91aab-0dce/_workitems/edit/7120\" data-vsp-mention=\"version:9.0\”>#7120</a>&nbsp;<br></div>"
        }
    ]
}
        # print(comment_data)
    
    lstComment = []
    newComment = ""
    # comments = issue.get_comments()
    commentCount = comment_data['count']
    print("comment count: " + str(commentCount))
    if len(comment_data) > 0:
        for comment in comment_data['comments']:
            comment['text'] = comment['text'].replace("&nbsp;", " ")
            soupComment = BeautifulSoup(comment['text'], "lxml")
            # newComment = soupComment.text
    
            # --------------------------------
            comments = soupComment.body.find_all(recursive=False)
            index = 0
            imgName = ""
            for s in comments:
                img = s.find('img')
                # newComment = s.text + "\n"
                if (img == None):
                    # newComment = ""
                    newComment = s.text + "\n"
                elif (img != None):
                    # newComment = s.text + "\n"
                    filename, file_extension = os.path.splitext(img['src'])
                    imgName = "img_comment_" + str(i['id']) + "_" + str(index) + file_extension
                    newComment += "!" + imgName + "!"
                    newComment = s.text + "\n" + "!" + imgName + "!"
    
                    index = index + 1
    
                print(newComment)
    
                # Download attached files of the workitem
                if(img != None):
                    # Create the output folder
                    path = "./attachedfiles/" + str(i['id']) + "/"
                    if not os.path.exists(path):
                        os.makedirs(path)
    
                    # Get the extension file
                    filename, file_extension = os.path.splitext(img['src'])
    
                    # Download the attached file and store it in the path
    
                    encode_string = img['src']
                    # url = encode_string.replace("data:image/jpeg;base64,", '')
                    if "data:image/jpeg;base64," in encode_string:
                        # Decode
                        url = encode_string.replace("data:image/jpeg;base64,", '')
                        print("------> download " + imgName + ".jpeg")
                        # with open(path + imgName, 'wb') as handler:
                        #     handler.write(base64.b64decode(img_data))
                        with open(path + imgName + ".jpeg", 'wb') as handler:
                            handler.write(base64.b64decode(url))
                    else:
                        img_data = requests.get(url=img['src'], headers=headers).content
                        print("------> download " + imgName)
                        with open(path + imgName, 'wb') as handler:
                            handler.write(img_data)
    
            # print(newComment)
            # newComment = soupComment.text
            created = comment['createdDate']
            lstComment.append({"body": newComment})
    
            # print(lstComment)
    
        return lstComment
    else:
        print('')
```

I want to iterate through above json to get the below json

```
"comments": [
            {
              "body": "So we need to add this directory of sample \n\n!img_comment_7107_0!\n\n",
              "author": “Jon,
            },
            {
              "body": "It does not make sense to files.\n\nWe first need to have a sample folder and then browse to it.  \n",
              "author": “Jon”,
            }
          ]
```

Expected output:
The second comment should not include the first comment. I do not have much experience, trying to learn on the go. Really appreciate if you help me what am i doing wrong, thanks!

Comment: Where you have `newComment += s.text + "\n"` you seem to be adding the second comment onto the first one which might be why it has both in the second one. I don't know what the rest of your code is but try using `newComment = ` instead of `newComment += `.

Comment: Hi @SleepyStew, I updated the question with original json which i want to iterate through comment[text] to genrate new json as mentioned in expected output. Thankyou for your propmt response.